# How to convert decimal to whole number in java

Tags: java, string, numbers

Hi i have an output as "1.234567E6" and similar. Now i want my output to be converted to 1234567. Could you please suggest how to acheive this? Splitting is one way but then E6 part handling i am not sure.

Also the output will be varying in nature, sometimes it would be 6 decimal places , sometimes 10

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Double.valueOf` then get the long value

```
long val = Double.valueOf("1.234567E6").longValue();
```

Or use BigDecimal with `longValueExact()` to avoid rounding error

```
long val = new BigDecimal("1.234567E10").longValueExact();
```

*Note: `longValueExact()` throws Arithmetic Exception if there is any fractional part of this BigDecimal.*

You can check the [demo here](https://onlinegdb.com/HkTO1jhn8)

Answer (score 0):

Use `DecimalFormat`, it's consistent and clear approach:

```
DecimalFormat decimalFormat = new DecimalFormat("0");
System.out.println( decimalFormat.format( 1.234567E6 ) );
```

In String case:

```
System.out.println( decimalFormat.format( Double.parseDouble("1.234567E6") ) );
```

Output in both cases

> 1234567

See code in action:  http://tpcg.io/9DsB3GRH